# Lorentz transform $\neq$ Jacobi matrix?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

One of my textbooks says that a contravariant vector $a^\lambda$ transforms according to $$a'^\mu=\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\lambda} a^\lambda,$$ when changing the inertial frame of reference ($x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\mu$). At the same time $$a'^\mu=\Lambda_{\mu\lambda}a^\lambda,$$ where $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transformation matrix.

This kind of confuses me as it implies the Jacobi-matrix w.r.t. to the basis vectors of the two frames of reference equals the Lorentz transformation. Shouldn't the first equation be
$$da'^\mu=\frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\lambda} da^\lambda\mathrm{~?}$$

Comment: I don't know what the "$da$" are supposed to be in your second equation - what is $d$? Also, since a transformation between inertial frames *is* just a Lorentz transformation, $x' = \Lambda x$ and the Jacobian is the Lorentz transformation, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: By $da$ i mean an infinitesimal change  of the vector components. Your last sentence confuses me. As far as I know the term Jacobian  refers to the determinant of the Jacobi matrix. How can this be the lorentz transformation?

Comment: Here is a discussion of Jacobians and Lorentz transformations: https://www.slac.stanford.edu/history/sureports/M-226.pdf They don't seem to be the same in that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Lorentz transform = Jacobi matrix. This is because Lorentz transformations are *linear*. Probably your textbook is going to discuss  *nonlinear* transformations, like the ones encountered in general relativity. In that case, the equation you wrote is the transformation law of the coordinates of a [tangent vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector).

Comment: Thx for making this clear